# Is there a good rule of thumb for determining if a react component should manage it's own state or not?

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to react, and really enjoying it. In creating components, is there a good rule of thumb (or simple generalization) to consider when deciding if a component should manage it's own state or not.

As example (*only as example*), an input that gets different classes added based on state, like 'hover', or 'not empty'...

Would it be better to create a component that manages those states internally or just handle that wherever I'm rendering an input?

I know this question may be 'primarily opinion based', but I'm hoping to get a general feel for how to think about it.

Thanks in advance,
-Ted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a constant internal battle that you'll just decide on down the line and you're right that it's primarily opinion based (meaning no answer will be correct). However, I can share my own experience and the process I take to decide on how to split the logic of my components.

I think of these things:

- How will having/not having that piece of logic affect unit tests? If the component would need too much setup to be tested, then I move some logic into it and away from a parent Container component.
- How often will I reuse the component? If it's many many times, then I look at the types of Container components that would render it and, again, if it seems like too much boilerplate is needed, then move the logic.
- Does the value change through its own behavior or based on outside queues? In your example of the hover, the behavior changes due to its own behavior so it feels like the className (a prop of itself) is reacting to the component itself.
- Most importantly, do you benefit from removing the logic and placing it in the Container? If you think that other component could benefit from knowing the hover state of your input field, then you may want to put the logic in the container. Otherwise you're abstracting away too much.

Application state management libraries such as Redux will often suggest to use their libraries as little as possible and instead rely on internal state of the component. I mention this because as you figure out where to put your logic, you have to think that about the end goal, which is usually to create a web application, with multiple components working together. Abstract too little and you end up creating non-reusable components. Abstract too much and you have tons of boilerplate and configuration lying around that could be trimmed by using internal state.

Answer (score 1):

Zeke has some absolutely great points. I'd just like to add my own guideline, which is:

- If the behavior of the component is the same, no matter where it's used, and is *not* tied to the behavior of the app/environment at large, then state should be internal
- otherwise, manage state elsewhere and pass in props